# Mail server redirect to another server

Tags: email

I have a site, which has a server with "Parallels Plesk Panel" installed. I want to send an email from that site a "Contact Us" message to info@domain.com email.

The problem is that this email was already created by one of the programmers using the google mail system (apparently you can create accounts there with a domain name different from gmail.com).

So now, the server rejects my message, telling me that it can't find an email with this name. It works fine when I send to any other domain, but when sending to the same one, it fails. I've created another email info2@domain.com and sent emails there and it works.

My question now is, how do I send emails to the existent info@domain.com which is already created in gmail without making the server block me. One of the options I saw at this panel is to redirect the request for that email to another mailing system (and to specify its IP). Maybe that would help if I would to put there gmails IP?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

Using my contact us form I am sending an email to info@domain.com. I get an SMTP error 550, can't find the mail box. When sending to anything but @domain.com it works. When adding that email to my server, it is also fine.

Now, the previous programmer already created info@domain.com, but not with our plesk panel, but using gmail server. Apparently, using gmail you can create an email of the type info@domain.com and not just info@gmail.com. The obvious problem is then that I try to send to this email. It sees that the server is domain.com and tries to find it there (same domain as the site from which I send the message). It fails and gives me the 550 error.

I want the server to send the email with that message to info@domain.com which is actually on gmail.

Comment: a lot of this makes no sense.

Comment: you want send an email using a "contact us form" from your site to a particular address - so the problem is?

Comment: Please share the error message you get when the email is rejected. This *might* make your question more easy to decipher.

Comment: maybe after the tenth read i think the issue is the MTA record for the domain is set to gmail or the mail server is set to use gmail for smtp. the solution would be to remove the mta record or set to local which it would be if the record was blank, and\or configure what ever mail-server you are using appropriately. then again with out access to your site, i'm just guessing

Comment: How is this PHP? You haven't mentioned anything PHP related or posted any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly, your problem is that two servers think they host the maildomain: your plesk server and gmail.

solution: disable local mail delivery for that domain on the plesk server and make sure plesk can correctly resolve the mx records of that domain , runing `dig mx +short domain.com` on the plesk server should return a google owned hostname, not the local hostname.

I don't own a plesk server, so I can't tell how how exactly to disable the mail domain, but a quick google search returns: http://www.serveridol.com/2011/03/16/disabling-email-service-for-a-domain-in-plesk/

Answer (score 0):

http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=email+form+service&ei=UTF-8&fr=chr-greentree_ff&type=827316

try a remote email form service. most hosting companies' mail servers are local. to do this, you would have to make your own .htaccess file which contains php.ini mail server settings.  i THINK this is correct.  you can install php yourself to see what those settings are.
this is something you will probably have to do through the web hosting control panel.

and by the way, XHTML is served up as HTML unless you configure the server to serve XHTML up as XHTML.  so use HTML when possible unless you know how to do that.  here's how.

http://jesusnjim.com/web-design/setup-test-server.html